# Python Tesseract with OpenCV and PIL not detecting characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I'm attempting to image recognize the text from a league of legends lobby so I can data mine.

I guess it's not recognizing the font, as the output of the program is: Doel seen aay

Source code:

```
import numpy as nm  
import pytesseract 
import cv2 
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image 
  
  
def imToString(): 
  
    # Path of tesseract executable 
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd ='C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\Tesseract.exe'
    while(True):  
        cap = ImageGrab.grab(bbox =(242, 884, 561, 990)) 
        cap.save('test.png')
        tesstr = pytesseract.image_to_string( 
                cv2.cvtColor(nm.array(cap), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),  
                lang ='eng',config='--psm 7')
        print(tesstr)
imToString()
```

[The image I'm using to test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXQMF.png)

Comment: I should note that newocr.com is able to detect it but other ocr websites cannot detect the "g" character. Interesting as my program can't detect much of anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need some preprocessing to image.

Try this one.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2    
img = cv2.imread('wXQMF.png', 0)
print(img.max(), img.min())
ret, thr1 = cv2.threshold(img, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

kernel_size_row = 3
kernel_size_col = 3
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)

erosion_image = cv2.erode(thr1, kernel, iterations=1)  #// make erosion image

cv2.imwrite('a.png',thr1)
```